# express middleware in function without ajax

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have below method

```
app.post('/auth', passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate('local', { session: false,scope: [] }), serialize, generateToken, respond);
```

this is working fine

Now I want like below

```
accesstokenController.auth =  function(req, res) {

  console.log('Here auth called');
  // execute middleware
  };

var oAthmiddleware =  [passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate(
  'local', {
    session: false,
    scope: []
  }), serialize, generateToken, respond];
```

call like this

```
router.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
    oauth.auth(req, res);
});
```

How to do this

Comment: Did my answer help you, anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware as:

*declare your middleware and handle authentication:*

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // do authentication
    // if fails
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="MyApp"');
    res.end('Unauthorized');
    // if success call next();
    next();
}
```

*declare your route:*

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
    // perform route related things
});
```